# How to add a column to a dataframe that is dependant on the avarage of a group in the dataframe or external dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, mean

I have a dataframe that I would like to calculate a new column for.
The column should be equal to x_i/E(x|Y=y_i). Where x_i is some element on row i and column X.
Codewise it would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Y=['y1'] * 2 + ['y2'] * 3 + 1 * ['y1'],
    X=range(1, 7)
))
    Y  X
0  y1  1
1  y1  2
2  y2  3
3  y2  4
4  y2  5
5  y1  6
```

and the final form should look like this

```
    Y  X  C_O
0  y1  1  1/3
1  y1  2  2/3
2  y2  3  3/4
3  y2  4  4/4
4  y2  5  5/4
5  y1  6  6/3
```

I tried something like but that did not work.

```
df["C_0"]=[df["X"]*df.groupby('Y')['X'].mean()]
```

another idea was to iterate over the list, but the dataframe has tens of thousands of items so it should probably be done some other, easier way.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the formula for the denominator "E(x|Y=y_i)" means?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, your grouping is correct with one exception -you need to transform it back to the df.

Do this:

```
df['C_O'] = df['X']/df.groupby(['Y'])['X'].transform('mean')
```

and you get:

```
    Y   X   C_O
0   y1  1   0.333333
1   y1  2   0.666667
2   y2  3   0.750000
3   y2  4   1.000000
4   y2  5   1.250000
5   y1  6   2.000000
```

change format:

```
df['C_O'] = df['X'].astype(str)+'/'+df.groupby(['Y'])['X'].transform('mean').astype(str)
```

and you get:

```
Y   X   C_O
0   y1  1   1/3
1   y1  2   2/3
2   y2  3   3/4
3   y2  4   4/4
4   y2  5   5/4
5   y1  6   6/3
```